# Want to format one workbook but i am wrinting the Macro in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have one workbook where I have some userform and code. Now based on this macro I am fetching the data into another workbook. Now From first excel I want to format the 2nd workbook after getting required data.

Below is my code:

```
 Set abc = objWorkbook1.Sheets(report_shtnm)
     abc.Activate
   With Sheet2.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(rw_reps_sht, cl_reps_sht))
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    .WrapText = True
   End With
```

The problem is its formatting the excel which has macro. Please help.

Comment: Are you facing an issue to pass the data? Can we split the code in WB1 and WB2 accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to declare your objects correctly and then simply work with them... See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    '~~> This workbook which has the macro
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet")

    '~~> The other workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Work with sheet1 in the workbook which has the macro
    With ws1
        '
        '~~> Your code here
        '
    End With

    '~~> Work with sheet1 in the second workbook
    With ws2
        '
        '~~> Your code here
        '
    End With
End Sub
```

If you notice that using this method doesn't even require you to use `.Select` or `.Activate` ;) You might also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) regarding `.Select` or `.Activate`